# css resizeable banner

Tags: css

Okay I found this tutorial "[Stretchy Image Header Banner with CSS](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/css-stretchy-image-header-banner/)" but the problem (as it listed in this tutorial is) is the height. The height gets real big as the browser is enlarge. Is there a way to resolve this? Since the banner would expand in proportion, the height will have to get bigger but I wonder if there is a better way to do this. Is there a way to start cropping the banner from the top by certain percentages as the banner is getting bigger? Any suggestion is much appreciated.

Comment: Can you make a fiddle and be more specific with your problem?

Comment: check this [link](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/css-stretchy-image-header-banner/)

Comment: it is showing how to create custom stretacble banner just depending on width. No height.

Comment: The tags field is not for you to fill with irrelevant tags. Please don't put those tags back in. One is enough.

Answer (score 1):

Set a `max-height` on the image to prevent it from getting to large vertically.

http://jsfiddle.net/8C9ms/

Comment: Is there a way to do automatic cropping from the top as the image gets bigger?

Comment: By using a max-height the image looks stretched out.

Comment: @charlie well, I picked a bad example of a placeholder image.  You should make the max height whatever the "natural" height of your banner image is.  If it can't extend to be super-wide, then you could set a `max-width` as well

Comment: But even that, the height would be very big. Perhaps CSS might be able to do it but what about jQuery or JavaScript? I want to crop the height as the image gets bigger.

Comment: The "natural" dimension is 1429x380. At this size, it looks fine below 500px but if the browser goes beyond this size, the height gets real big, and I like a smooth transition of cropping from the top of the image as the image gets bigger and reducing the crop as the image gets smaller due to resizing of the browser.

Comment: I think that you may not understand the definition of "crop?"

Comment: Okay, I may used the wrong term. Anyway I tried setting margin-top to negative value and it does seem to hide the top but I need it to transition as the user resize the browser.

Comment: You may be able to use media queries to do this

Comment: Yes, I thought of that but media queries does not provide a fluid transition.